# Tezos Contracts Compiling Error

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, compile

I am just days into learning how to build a dapp on Tezos for my thesis. I tried replicating the steps from Claude's tutorial - https://hackernoon.com/build-your-first-dapp-on-tezos-rwgl3ymb

I ran into a problem (unknown subcommand compile-contract) when I was trying to compile the contracts via truffle in the terminal. Would be great if you can tell me what is causing the error or point me right direction :D Many thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Truffle, but Ligo is in very active development, and I believe they recently changed the `compile-contract` subcommand to `compile contract` (note lack of dash.) If you do `ligo man compile` you can see all of the other sub-commands of `compile`. I prefer `ligo man compile -v 0` to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure truffle doesn't support tezos updates anymore.
I've switched months ago (after running constantly into issues like the one you're describing) to compiling directly with the ligo cli, and testing
and deploying contracts with pytezos.
https://ligolang.org/docs/manpages/ligo
https://pytezos.org/contents.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your clarification! I will look into the links you provided!